# Material UI tabs with Nested Routes - Refreshing page error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router

So I'm trying to implement material UI tabs with React Router Dom (Nested Routes), I made the routes but I'm facing an issue:

The tabs are working fine here as shown in the images below

[image]

[image]

The issue is that when I refresh the page it shows the password tab content with the general tab content! as shown in the image below

[image]

**`App.js`** *The first path should be the page of General Tab*:

```
<Route path="/account" element={user ? <Settings /> : <Register />}>
  <Route path="/account/profile" element={<EditProfile />} />
  <Route path="/account/password" element={<EditPassword />} />
  <Route path="/account/social_profiles" element={<SocialProfiles />} />
  <Route path="/account/notifications" element={<EditNotifications />} />
</Route>
```

**`VerticalTabs.jsx`:**

```
<Tabs
    orientation="vertical"
    variant="scrollable"
    value={value}
    onChange={handleChange}
    aria-label="Vertical tabs example"
    sx={{ borderRight: 1, borderColor: 'divider' }}
  >

    <Tab component={Link} to={"/account"} label="General" {...a11yProps(0)} />
    <Tab component={Link} to={"/account/profile"} label="Edit Profile" {...a11yProps(1)} />
    <Tab component={Link} to={"/account/password"} label="Password" {...a11yProps(2)} />
    <Tab component={Link} to={"/account/social_profiles"} label="Social Profiles" {...a11yProps(3)} />
    <Tab component={Link} to={"/account/notifications"} label="Notifications" {...a11yProps(4)} />
    <Tab label="Sessions" {...a11yProps(5)} />
    <Tab label="Delete Account" {...a11yProps(6)} />
  </Tabs>
  
  <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
    <General />
  </TabPanel>
  <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
  </TabPanel>

  <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
  </TabPanel>

  <TabPanel value={value} index={3}>
  </TabPanel>

  <TabPanel value={value} index={4}>
```

Comment: No need to route unless you specifically want the route listed in the address bar. Just render each component in the tab panel

Comment: I actually want the route listed in the address bar